# Where is lldpd package for Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora-20, lldp

I used to `apt-get install lldpd` on Debian but now I can't find same package for Fedora. Needed command line tool is `lldpcli`. Usage example:

```
lldpcli show neighbors
```

Does fedora has this tool too?

Comment: Why the down vote? Is the question against server fault rules in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The [project website's installation page](http://vincentbernat.github.io/lldpd/installation.html#fedora-rhel-centos-suse) explains that you must use openSUSE's repository since the packages are not present in the official repositories, or you can build from source.

The instructions for using openSUSE's repository are [here](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:vbernat&package=lldpd).

Comment: I would suggest using @MichaelHampton's suggestion rather than mine.

Comment: I prefer to use the openSUSE's repo. lldpad seems to be a different tool with different commands, despite it has the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Fedora and RHEL use [`lldpad`](http://www.open-lldp.org/) rather than `lldpd`.

```
yum install lldpad
```